# Jquery slider - call function on each step

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-slider

Function not triggered when moving slider to fast. I'm calling function using "slide" with Jquery UI slider. Is there a way to force it to call the function on each step? Here's the code:

```
var last = currentZoom;
$( "#slider-vertical" ).slider({
    orientation: "vertical",
    range: "min",
    min: 0.2,
    max: 1.3,
    value: currentZoom,
    step: 0.1,
slide: function( event, ui ) {
    if (ui.value > last) {
        zoomIn();
    }else{
        zoomOut();
    }
    console.log($( "#slider-vertical" ).slider('value'));
    last = ui.value;
}
});
```

So just to recap, while sliding it to fast it doesnt recognize the slide and it leads to it on skipping steps resulting in inaccurate values.

Thanks

Comment: I've been unable to replicate the issue. Tested here https://jsfiddle.net/Twisty/xxLLv3zj/

Comment: Might help to review your zoom functions. Could you include those in your post?

Comment: @TellJohn did you got any solution for this issue if so kindly share the same,Thanks